# env->GetFloatArrayElements error ANdroid

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, java-native-interface

android project:
i HAve c. file :

```
      /* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
     #include <com_jp_algi_Corelib.h>
           /* Header for class com_jp_algi_Corelib */
       #ifdef __cplusplus
       #define EXTCFUNC extern "C"
          #elseif
        #define EXTCFUNC extern
        #endif




        JNIEXPORT jfloatArray JNICALL Java_com_jp_algi_Corelib_vector
        (JNIEnv * env, jobject clazz, jfloatArray input){

      jfloatArray result;




              }

                jfloat* flt1 = env->GetFloatArrayElements(input,0)
```

;insiperd by : Eiegen android         in the stackflow.

and there is some error:

```
C:/AA/FileBroswerActivity/jni/com_jp_algi_Corelib.c:23: error: 'env' undeclared here (not in a function)
C:/AA/FileBroswerActivity/jni/com_jp_algi_Corelib.c:23: error: 'input' undeclared here (not in a function)
/cygdrive/c/android-ndk-r5c/build/core/build-binary.mk:217: recipe for target `/cygdrive/c/AA/FileBroswerActivity/obj/local/armeabi/objs/com_jp_algi_Corelib/com_jp_algi_Corelib.o' failed
make: *** [/cygdrive/c/AA/FileBroswerActivity/obj/local/armeabi/objs/com_jp_algi_Corelib/com_jp_algi_Corelib.o] Error 1
```

16:52:03 Build Finished (took 672ms)

Comment: Please provide **all** relevant code, the exact (compiler) error messages, and - most importantly - do ask a question.

Comment: `jfloat* flt1 = env->GetFloatArrayElements(input,0)` is not inside a function body, as the error message indicates. Also, please do put some effort into editing your question. At the very least format the code so that it can easily be read.

Answer (score 0):

Your post is really unclear but your files should looks like this

- .h file:

  ```
  #include <jni.h>

  #ifdef __cplusplus
  extern "C" {
  #endif

  jfloatArray JNICALL Java_com_jp_algi_Corelib_vector(JNIEnv * env, jobject clazz, jfloatArray input);

  #ifdef __cplusplus
  }
  #endif
  ```
- .cpp file:

  ```
  #include "yourheader.h"

  #ifdef __cplusplus
  extern "C" {
  #endif

  jfloatArray JNICALL Java_com_jp_algi_Corelib_vector(JNIEnv * env, jobject clazz, jfloatArray input)
  {
    jfloat* flt1 = env->GetFloatArrayElements(input,0);
  }

  #ifdef __cplusplus
  }
  #endif
  ```

**Edit**(after your edit):

```
jfloat* flt1 = env->GetFloatArrayElements(input,0);
```

is outside function body

Comment: ok tahnks, whats the differnce between .c file and .cpp??? becouse c. throws this errors and .cpp no but something like this:

Comment: make: *** No rule to make target `/cygdrive/c/AA/FileBroswerActivity/jni/com_jp_algi_Corelib.c', needed by `/cygdrive/c/AA/FileBroswerActivity/obj/local/armeabi/objs/com_jp_algi_Corelib/com_jp_algi_Corelib.o'.  Stop.